# How to remove all styles for certain page template?

Tags: page-template, css

I know how to create child themes and page templates.  I have a child theme of Salient called Salient-Child, and I have a page template called blankPage.php.

For all pages that use this template, I want there to be no CSS loaded at all.

I'm aware of `wp_register_script, wp_deregister_script, wp_deregister_style, wp_dequeue_style`, etc, but I'm not sure where/how to use them.

I've tried typing some of those functions within blankPage.php itself, and I've also tried editing functions.php.  I've tried using a conditional with `if(is_page_template('blankPage.php')){...}`.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to solve the problem, and it was so simple that I'm shocked I've never seen this mentioned by anyone before.

First, I deleted my entire child theme so that I could start over from a fresh place.

Then, I used https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-click-child-theme/ to create a brand new child theme of Salient.

Then, in the **Appearance > Editor** menu, I viewed the `functions.php` file and noticed that it had pregenerated `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );` and `function theme_enqueue_styles()` for me.

So I simply wrapped the contents of the function within `if ( !is_page_template( 'rawHtmlPage.php' ) ) { ...}`.

Answer (score 13):

You can remove specific styles and java scripts for specific page template like below. Add the code into the `functions.php` file of your current theme. To see the list of all JS and CSS you may want to use a plugin like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-list-dependencies/

```
/**
 * Remove specific java scripts.
 */
function se_remove_script() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'blankPage.php' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'some-js' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'some-other-js' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'se_remove_script', 99 );

/**
 * Remove specific style sheets.
 */
function se_remove_styles() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'blankPage.php' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'some-style' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'some-other-style' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'se_remove_styles', 99 );
```

You can remove all styles and java scripts in one go for specific page template like below. Add the code into the `functions.php` file of your current theme.

```
/**
 * Remove all java scripts.
 */
function se_remove_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    if ( is_page_template( 'blankPage.php' ) ) {
        $wp_scripts->queue = array();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'se_remove_all_scripts', 99 );

/**
 * Remove all style sheets.
 */
function se_remove_all_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( is_page_template( 'blankPage.php' ) ) {
        $wp_styles->queue = array();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'se_remove_all_styles', 99 );
```

Comment: Your `se_remove_all_styles` seems right on track for what I'm hoping for, but when I just tried it, it removed all styles from ALL pages, regardless of template.  I don't know why, given that there is an "If" statement.  Any ideas on how to debug why this would be happening for me? Thanks!

Comment: Are you providing correct path for the template file inside the if checking ?